# bind_param and execute in loop?

Tags: php, mysqli

Is it possible to invoke `bind_param` and `execute` iteratively, or must I prepare a statement at the beginning of each iteration?

```
$query = $db->prepare('...');
foreach ($dataItem as $item) {
    $query->bind_param($v1, $v2, ..., $item);
    $query->execute();
}
$query->close();
```

If I do have to recreate the statement each iteration, is it possible to optimize this process?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to prepare a statement at the beginning of each iteration.

The concept of prepared statements is to reuse the same statement multiple times in the first place, so it's good to go to prepare once and execute it multiple times.

See also [this note](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#103730) on the manual page.